# Get Object or Space X,Y,Z Coordinates from UV Coordinates

Tags: python, scripting, uv, coordinates

[image]

From within python, I'm looking to get the (X,Y,Z) coordinates in global space of where the dots are in my UV image.

So for an X,Y coordinate in a UV image, how do i get the (X,Y,Z) of where that coordinate was placed in global space?

Comment: You can probably get the xyz-coordinate by using an inverted parametrization formula. This is rather difficult... Can you explain why you need this? There might be an easier workflow for what you are trying to achieve...

Comment: @BertVdB this is a simulation im running for an ML problem